# what is the meaning that alias passed an array parameter in perl?

Tags: perl

what is the meaning that  alias passed an array parameter in perl? Is right the following code?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@myarray = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
&my_sub(@myarray);

sub my_sub {
    my (@subarray) = @_;
    print @subarray;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by an "alias".  That has a specific meaning in Perl.  Could you rewrite the question without using the word "alias"?  Also, what are you trying to accomplish?  We can't figure out if its the right code unless we know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
@myarray = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
&my_sub(@myarray);
sub my_sub {
    my (@subarray) = @_;
    print @subarray;
}

Comment: I want know above code using alias method in subroutine？

Comment: @baozailove: All you have done is reiterate your question. Please rewrite it more clearly without using the word `alias`.

Comment: @Borodin:I very sorry,but i still thanks for each person's answer.My english is not very well,i want the answer that i have accept in the following!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term *alias* describes that multiple names can point to the same data, without the syntactic restriction of references.

In Perl, aliases can be created arbitrarily by e.g. [`Data::Alias`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aAlias), but there are a few constructs that create aliases themself.

1. The foreach-loop. The current element is an alias to the original element in the list:

   ```
   my @array = 1 .. 5;
   for my $elem (@array) {
      $elem++; # $elem is an alias to $array[$i]
   }
   # the @array is now 2 .. 6.
   ```
2. Subroutine arguments. Perl subroutines are called with a flat list of scalars (i.e. collections like hashes or arrays get flattened into this list). This list is accessible via the `@_` array. All elements in this array are aliases to the parameters.

   ```
   sub alias_increment {
     for my $elem (@_) {
        $elem++;
     }
   }

   my @array = 1 .. 5;
   alias_increment(@array);
   # array now is 2 .. 6.
   ```

   Do note that in this example, `@_` is not an alias to `@array`, but `$_[$i]` is an alias to `$array[$i]`.

   Using these aliases allows you to have out-arguments, but that makes for akward APIs imho.

You should also note that Perl usually has *copying semantics*. This means that the statement `$foo = $bar` usually *copies* the data of `$bar` to `$foo`. The copy is a seperate entity, and if the original was an alias, the copy won't be an alias itself. When copying in list context, all elements are copied. This means that

```
my @array = @_;
```

does the same thing as

```
my @array;
$array[0] = $_[0];
# ...
```

This *breaks all aliasing*.

This is in fact used as a pattern in Perl to do “call by value” and allows to limit side-effects of subroutines.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
sub my_sub {
    my (@subarray) = @_;
    print @subarray;
}
```

Makes a *copy* of the array that was passed into the subroutine.  This is correct if you want to modify the array in your subroutine without modifying the original array.

The correct way to call a subroutine in modern Perl is just `my_sub(@myarray);`.  You should not use `&`.

Comment: Thank you!!But in subroutie,if you add 'my' or 'local' to front of variable,the original array will never be modified.

Comment: @baozailove, the key here is that you are copying the array to another variable.  That is why it is not modified.  Also, note that `my` and `local` are very different.